# onCreateContextMenu isn't called

Tags: android

Looks like onCreateContextMenu isn't called at all, after setting a custom adapter for the ListView and registering with the ContextMenu. What am i doing wrong? Here's my code for the main activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    dbAdapter.open();
    workersArray=dbAdapter.getAllWorkersAndHoursToday();
    dbAdapter.close();

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.workers_list);
    CustomArrayAdapter adapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.workers_row, R.id.workers_name, workersArray);
    this.adapter=adapter;
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    registerForContextMenu(listView);

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    if (Utils.isSaved(this)){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SavedActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    Log.d("debug","Called onCreateContextMenu");

    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_popup_main, menu);
}
```

and the getView for the custom ArrayAdapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View row = convertView;
    WorkerHolder holder = null;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new WorkerHolder();
        holder.txtName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.workers_name);
        holder.txtHours = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.worked_hours_today);

        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (WorkerHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    Worker worker = data[position];
    holder.txtName.setText(worker.getName());
    holder.txtHours.setText("" + worker.getHoursWorkedToday());

    return row;
}
```

Thanks for your answers

Comment: it should be called on long press

Comment: AFAIK ContextMenu should include a "built-in" long press listener... am I wrong?

Comment: you are right. It is fired on long press

Comment: yes, in my code the log inside oncreatecontextmenu doesn't show so there must be some mistake

Comment: Figured out that the problem was having two buttons inside each row of the listview. I will try to register for context menu a child textview inside each row.